# iOS and SQL issue

Tags: ios, sqlite, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an app that uses an SQLite database for user choices of backgrounds, icons, fonts, etc. I didn't create it, so, I have to use what I have, as, I have a rather large installed base, and am not inclined to switch to CoreData at this point. Don't want to piss off the current users. I also am not really up to speed on SQLite or CoreData.

I was using a custom grid view to display the backgrounds and icons. All of that has been changed to UICollectionView with a UICollectionViewCell.

In the SQL file, the base set is one table of 16 items. Really two (one for icons and the other for backgrounds). These are a part of the base app. In-app purchasing unlocks other "sets". These other sets are in a second table. Yes, separate tables for icons and backgrounds.

I have changed the ID numbers in the first table to start at 0. Previously they started at 1. I can now select and change both icons and backgrounds at will without issue and get the correctly selected item.

Except... when I select an item that is in the secondary icon or background table. 
I have altered the ID numbers in the second table to start at one ID higher than the ending ID in the base set table.

But... the first item in the second table is being skipped. Selection of any item in the second table is showing the icon or background directly prior to the selected item. (ie. I select ID 21, I get ID 20 displayed). The first item in the secondary table is showing the last item in the secondary table.

So, my question... should the IDs in the second table start over at 0? Should they start at 1? Or is there another way to solve the skipping and incorrect selection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Double-check that you're specifying the right column in the SELECT statement.  If you specify a match on 21 you will get the row that matches 21, but SQLite sorta throws in their own ID table "for free".  (Also double-check that your updated SQLite table is actually installed.  Generally if you update the table you must delete the app from the simulator/device to have the new table copied over.)

Comment: The columns in the SQL... one with IDs, the other with the image name. Obviously, I changed the ID column. Yes, I remove the old db file from Xcode's project manager before replacing with the altered one. And, yes, I know that the app must be deleted from simulator. Pretty normal... big changes require the app to install fresh.